Quantization into Phonon in a multi-basis crystal
I am quite frustrated in quantizing the vibration of a multi-basis crystal.
The specific point that confuses me is the potential term, which hinders me from decoupling the Hamiltonian as the sum of HO-like Hamiltonians. First, introducing Lagrangian, denoting $l$, $j$ as lattice index and basis index, respectively, the classical Lagrangian can be expressed as follows:
\begin{align}
L = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j, l}M_j\dot{\xi}_{l, j}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j,l, j', l'}D_{j,j'}(R_l-R_{l'})\xi_{l, j}\xi_{l', j'}
\end{align}
, where $\xi$ is the displacement vector, and $R$ is the lattice vector. The typical treatment is to insert the periodic ansatz $\xi_{l,j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k\xi_{k,j}e^{ik(R_l+\tau_j)}$, where $\tau$ is the position vector for each basis denoted by the index $j$. The substitution immediately yields the desirable form for the kinetic term, but the potential term becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{\{j\},\{l\},\{k\}}D_{j,j'}(R_l-R_{l'})\xi_{k',j'}\xi_{k,j}e^{ik(R_l+\tau_j)+ik'(R_l'+\tau_j')}
\end{align}
which does not become like $\approx\sum\omega(k)^2\xi_k\xi_{-k}$. I think it seems an additional diagonalization process should be done on $D$ (and possibly n.n. coupling assumption), but then I do not have any idea how the displacement in phonon coordinates can be expressed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\delta \mathbf{R}_l^a = \sum_{\mathbf{q}\alpha} A_{\mathbf{q}\alpha}^a\hat{\mathbf{\epsilon}}_{\mathbf{q}\alpha}^a e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{R}_l^a}(a_{\mathbf{q}\alpha}+a_{\mathbf{-q}\alpha}^\dagger)
\end{align*}
, where $\alpha$ is the coordinate index (${x,y,z}$) and $a$ is the basis index. This is actually equation 10.8 in Cohen's condensed matter textbook. If the diagonalization should be done, then the suitable transformation matrix should be also multiplied in front of $(a_{\mathbf{q}\alpha}+a_{\mathbf{-q}\alpha}^\dagger)$? Also, in the last equation excerpted from Cohen's textbook, should not the basis index $a$ also be labeled to the creation operator?
Also, if possible, could someone please provide me a material that deals with the above issue I mentioned in the course of quantizing vibrations into phonons? Thank you very much in advance.
